# Using Data Annotations inside a Web Forms project

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, data-annotations, asp.net-4.0

When I use component model [data annotation attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490428.aspx) outside of the MVC framework context (inside a Web Forms website project), can I then invoke the built-in process to check the annotated data and retrieve the results?

The [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) interface provides the validation mechanism but I still need a hook into that process for retrieval of the [ValidationResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult.aspx)s. That's what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following working sample to validate the annotations from inside my website project.

If anybody knows a better way, please feel free to share your answer too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;


// This method is on the same class that has been annotated with data attributes.
// That's why the validation logic references 'this'.
// 
public override void Validate()
{
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
    List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(this, context, results, true);
    if (results.Any()) // do whatever you want with the results.
        throw new Exception("validation failed");

}
```